# I'm trying to get a StringVar from its variable name, but getting an exception: _tkinter.TclError

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#! /bin/python

from tkinter import Tk,Entry,StringVar

def my_callback(var, index, mode):
    print (app.getvar(var))

app=Tk()
entry_var=StringVar(master=app)
entry_var.trace_add("write",callback=my_callback)
entry=Entry(app,textvariable=entry_var)
entry.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

gives:

> _tkinter.TclError: can't read "PY_VAR0": no such variable

Did I do something incorrect, or is something wrong with my system?

Answer:
The suggested similar question gave me enough hints to resolve this. Basically, `getvar` doesn't work for Tk variables, only normal widgets in a normal hierarchy. So you have to use `globalgetvar` instead. You can use the root/toplevel as a reference. You don't have to assign a master to the StringVar, nor does that change anything. You can give it a name, but that isn't necessary to get the question code to work right.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't trying to use `var.get()` instead of `app.getvar(var)`? What are you trying to do in side the function?

Comment: 1) yes
2) execute logic

Comment: Use `app.globalgetvar(var)` instead